# Adding custom confirm message box, jQuery to highlight bold font does not work

Tags: javascript, jquery, modal-dialog, styling, confirm

I know that Alert and Confirm cannot be styled, so I looked around and found an example of how to customise your own. However the example I found works online, but I could not get it to work in my application. The function looks like below:

```
$(function () {
  $("#dialog-message").showModalDialog({
    modal: true,
    buttons: {
      Ok: function () {
        $(this).dialog("close");
      }
    }
  });
});
```

While the div that contain the message looks like below:

```
<div id="dialog-message" title="Download complete">
  <p>
    <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-circle-check" style="float:left; margin:0 7px 50px 0;"></span>
    Your files have downloaded successfully into the My Downloads folder.
  </p>
  <p>
    Currently using <b>36% of your storage space</b>.
  </p>
</div>
```

The problem that the message printed out into my page and the div is not read as a dialog box. 
What am I missing?

Comment: Have you included whatever library adds the `showModalDialog()` method? Check for errors in the console

Comment: Yes I did add the library

Answer (score 1):

Here you go with a solution https://jsfiddle.net/jbzgvzxk/

```js
$(function () {
  $("#dialog-message").dialog({
    modal: true,
    buttons: {
      Ok: function () {
        $(this).dialog("close");
      }
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<div id="dialog-message" title="Download complete">
  <p>
    <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-circle-check" style="float:left; margin:0 7px 50px 0;"></span>
    Your files have downloaded successfully into the My Downloads folder.
  </p>
  <p>
    Currently using <b>36% of your storage space</b>.
  </p>
</div>
```

My assumption is you are using `jQueryUI`.
Instead of `showModalDialog`, it should be `dialog`.

**Reference Document:** https://jqueryui.com/dialog/#modal-confirmation

Please check the library & it's order of linking in the solution as well.

Hope this will help you.

Comment: It does not work, as I use this in a asp .net webform

Comment: Can you check your browser network panel whether `jQueryUI` library files are loading or not?

Comment: Yes they are jQueryUI is loading, but as I wrote I'm implementing it in an ASP .NET webform, and I need to in some way embede the div I have into the javascript method so it is loaded when the page is loaded.

Comment: The solution works when I implemented in a simple html file, but NOT when it is inside the ASP project

Answer (score 0):

this one is working fine

you need this code in java script

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$( "#dialog-message" ).dialog({
  dialogClass: "no-close",
  buttons: [
    {
      text: "OK",
      click: function() {
        $( this ).dialog( "close" );
      }
    }
  ]
});

});
```

you must make sure to import this 3 files to the page

1. https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.js //Jquery
2. https://code.jquery.com/ui/jquery-ui-git.js // Jquery UI
3. https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.css
   // jquery ui CSS